# JMX and Tomcat: create and use MBeans in a servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jmx

does anybody have some ideas on how to achieve that? Or even a good documentation on how to do that?

Basicly everything is done in a test standalone version (by a java client or jconsole I am able to call mbeans methods and everything works fine), but I need to put it in my Tomcat servlet....

Thanks for every suggestions!

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tomcat docs [on monitoring](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/monitoring.html) describe how to enable JMX for Tomcat process's JVM.  The short answer is you have to get the com.sun.management.jmxremote.* system properties set somehow -- either through the CATALINA_OPTS, or the start up script or the Windows service definition.

And have MBeans in your deployed app(s), of course.

Answer (score -1):

Just attach the jconsole to your Tomcat process and you should be able to see any MBeans defined by your Servlet.